# Block a specific image on a specific site

Tags: google-chrome, web, pictures

There is a forum I visit with a large banner image on every page that takes up half my screen.

I want to block this image, but I can't just block all images for the site because the thread navigation buttons are also images. The image is served from the same address so no /hosts rules.

Any tricks/tools/add-ins to block a specific element in Chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just used ad blocker to block the element on the page.

1. Download adblocker from extension store.
2. Right click on image
3. Click: don't show me this ad.

Comment: @MartinBeckett most adblockers allow a good level of granularity in their blocking. With AdBlock Plus for example you can block entire domains right down to individual files or even do pattern matching so that you get only particularly named files. If you know they store their banners or adverts in a specific directory then you can instead target that.